# How to split a Python list

Tags: python, dictionary

I am querying a fusion table and getting all the information in a list. Now I want to split these lists. To give you a better idea, my fusion table has the following columns - USStates, NOFU2008, NOFU2009, NOFU2010, 12MI%, 24MI%, USStateCode. Here is the code that I have -

```
service = build('fusiontables', 'v1', developerKey=API_KEY)
query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_ID
response = service.query().sql(sql=query).execute()
data = response['rows']
```

This returns the data in the following format -

```
[[u'Alabama', 290060.0, 694020.0, 1452300.0, 1.093, 4.007, u'US-AL'], [u'Alaska', 46400.0, 160760.0, 300840.0, 0.871, 5.484, u'US-AK'], [u'Arizona', 320320.0, 1017020.0, 2234400.0, 1.197, 5.976, u'US-AZ']]
```

From this I just want to filter the data into different variables. For example,

```
var data2008 - [[u'US-AL', 290060.0], [u'US-AK', 46400.0], [u'US-AZ', 320320.0], [u'US-AR', 295280.0]]
```

How do I do this? I understand that I will have to run the data through a `for` loop and add the state codes and NOFU2008 to a new list.

Comment: You should at least try first and then show us what you've tried.

Comment: @2rs2ts - I tried executing two queries one with USStateCode, NOFU2008 and one with USStateCode, NOFU2009. But that did not work. I did not post that as you would not be able to run it and test it why it does not work for me. Also I thought this alternate approach is also reasonable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're doing this the wrong way, as the other answer implies, but if you MUST....

```
data2008 = {x[-1]:x[1] for x in data}
# {u'US-AL': 290060.0, u'US-AK', 46400.0, ...}
# data2008["US-AL"] == 290060.0
## NOTE THAT DICTIONARIES ARE UNORDERED -- IF YOU NEED TO KEEP THE
## ORDER FOR ANY REASON OTHER THAN DISPLAYING IT TO THE USER (FOR
## WHICH for line in sorted(data2008) WILL WORK PERFECTLY, DO NOT
## DO THIS
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data = [[u'Alabama', 290060.0, 694020.0, 1452300.0, 1.093, 4.007, u'US-AL'], [u'Alaska', 46400.0, 160760.0, 300840.0, 0.871, 5.484, u'US-AK'], [u'Arizona', 320320.0, 1017020.0, 2234400.0, 1.197, 5.976, u'US-AZ']]

data_2008 = [[state[6], state[1]] for state in data]
```

which results in

```
[[u'US-AL', 290060.0], [u'US-AK', 46400.0], [u'US-AZ', 320320.0]]
```